# Unable to reduce the code (combine cout with exit)

Tags: c++, c, linux, exit, cout

I'm allowed to insert only 10 lines (strict) of codes into my program. I have optimized to program to a concise one. I have posted the code below.

```
    if (std::find(outvar.begin(), outvar.end(), line[x].tokens[0]) == outvar.end() ||             (std::find(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(), line[x].tokens[4]) == inputs.end())
 {
 cerr << "Undefined variable " << endl;  
 exit(1);
 }


if (opr[x].type == "MUL" && opr[x1].asap_value == my_cycle + 1)
{
opr[x1].asap_value = my_cycle + 2; 
update_slack();
update_matrix(opr[x1].opid, 0);
}


if (latency < (opr[p2].asap_value + opr[p2].latency_op - 1) || opr[p2].asap_value == 0) 
{
cerr << "Latency value is too less for this circuit \n"; return -1;
}
```

This alone takes 10 lines and I have 2 more compulsory lines of codes that has to be added. I'n unable to further reduce it. Basically I'm looking to combine the err(cout) statement along with the exit (return) statement into a single statement.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What constitutes a line? You could write it all on one line.

Comment: Is the restriction lines of code or size of executable or size of data?

Comment: I'm not looking for optimization in general. Just reduce the number of lines. And each line is such till the semi colon.

Comment: So `if` conditionals don't count as a line?

Comment: What if you used commas instead of semicolons?

Comment: cout is not C so the C tag should be removed

Answer (score 1):

You could make this all into one line using commas:

```
opr[x1].asap_value = my_cycle + 2, update_slack(), update_matrix(opr[x1].opid, 0);
```

Not sure if this is considered cheating. You haven't specified what the rules are exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that there is no obvious relationship between the number of statements and the code efficiency. That is because, for example the statement `cout<<x;` is not a single instructions for your processor. There can be hundreds or even thousands of instructions that the processor must execute in order to achieve the goal of that statement. Also, there are some statements, like `a = b + c;` that are translated into 2-3 instructions.

So, by reducing the number of statements, you don't optimize the code. There are other ways of optimization, like using a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: Yes. As you said, I'm just looking to reduce the number of lines.

Comment: Why? There is no point in doing that, as your code will get probably harder to read and potentially more inefficient.

Comment: I think this number of lines requirement is not for code efficiency, but rather some externally imposed restriction (maybe a homework assignment)